# Create A Variable Using a Previously Variable Created

Tags: sql-server

I calculated a time span variable `Checkin_to_triage` using the `Datediff` function and would like to categorize that values from that variable into new variable, `Pre_Arrival`. I've tried using the code below but am obviously getting a `invalid column name 'checkin_to_triage'` error message due to the `IIf ([checkin_to_triage]<60 And [checkin_to_triage]>0,'PreArrival','Null') AS Pre_Arrival` code, as the `Pre_Arrival` variable is not a field within my dataset.

```
use EMTCQIData

DECLARE @StartDate Date
DECLARE @EndDate Date

Set @StartDate = '01/01/2018'
Set @EndDate = '12/31/2018'

SELECT *, 
  Format([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],'dddd') AS [Checkin_Day], 
  Format([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],'dddd dd/mm/yyyy') AS checkin_day_date, 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),[CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],108) as Checkin_Time, 
  DateDiff("n",CHECKIN_DATE_TIME,triage_date_time) AS checkin_to_triage,
  IIf ([checkin_to_triage]<60 And [checkin_to_triage]>0,'PreArrival','Null') AS Pre_Arrival
FROM ED_TAT_MASTER
WHERE (CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate)
```

Comment: btw, for future reference, `checkin_to_triage` --as used in your sample query-- is not a variable.   It is an alias.   There is a big difference.   `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are variables.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman, learning new SQL lingo every day!

Comment: You cannot use alias (`checkin_to_triage`) as a field name here. replace it with the expression.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev, how would that I do that? Sorry I'm still a beginner at SQL

Comment: use `datediff(...)` instead of `checkin_to_triage`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev not sure if I'm following, do you mean something like this? 
    `IIf (DateDiff("n",CHECKIN_DATE_TIME,triage_date_time)<60 And 
     DateDiff("n",CHECKIN_DATE_TIME,triage_date_time)>0,'PreArrival','Null') 
     AS Pre_Arrival`

Comment: It looks ugly but should work

Comment: It does! Thank you!